# Is it possible to use AdGuard Home with DNSSEC to DNS over TLS but with a Bind9 internal DNS Server downstream of AdGuard?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, tls, bind

In the diagram I threw together the left hand side shows my current LAN's DNS query path, I would like to have it as shown on the right hand side with AdGuard and DNSSEC or DNS over TLS if possible I have a decent physical Proxmox host capable of having two separate VMs if needed, is this possible?

I'm currently running an Ubuntu Server VM on a Proxmox Host, running Bind9 DNS for my internal LAN (home lab), I want to setup AdGuard on a seprate VM and use DNSSEC or DNS over TLS for everything upstread of my bind9 box.

My Current DNS query path is Netowrk 192.168.0.0/24 > 192.168.0.253 Bind9Server (This handles requests for A records and CNAMES etc for private IP ranges, if not found is passed upstream) > 8.8.8.8 (Public DNS for anything outside my LAN)

Instead I want DNS queries (if passed upstream by my Bind9 Server) to be passed over DNSSEC (or DNS over TLS) to my AdGuard VM for secure ad blocking and encypted public queries. Please can someone say if this is possible or if I need to change my topology etc? Any pointers would be much appreciated.[My Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrgJT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've done almost exactly what you've described: using bind (though in my case I use both bind, and also free-ipa, which run a bind under the hood to provide DNS) to my home LAN. Private servers on the LAN are resolved by BIND, and an ADGuard Home server is used as forwarder for everything else.
All that is required, is to specify the ADGuard server in your BIND option config like this:

```
forwarders {
    # AdGuard-Home filtering
    10.0.2.3;
};
forward only;
```

That's it!

DNSSEC is enabled by default nowadays on BIND and you only need to enable it on ADGuard, if all you want is to make sure the response from external are authentic. On the other hand, if you want to also encrypt your local zone records, there will be some additional configurations. Although personally, I think it's rather an overkill for small LANs, it's a decision entirely up to you.

Unless you feel sensitive about your DNS queries, I also don't see much value in implementing DNS query over TLS, since all it does, is just to obscure the DNS traffic from eavesdropping. Again, it's up to you.

There is one little side-effect resulted from this setup: as the ADGuard server filter out hosts by returning 0.0.0.0, it's effectively altering query results, exactly the kind of thing DNSSEC is designed to detect. Don't be surprised when you see LOTS and LOTS of "broken chain of trust" errors in the log.